# Javascript and prototype inheritance issue

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Is there any way to stop instances of a function from inheriting property's from each other? I was reading an article on Javascripts prototype object and read the following.

"It's important to note that the prototype is "live". Objects are passed by reference in JavaScript, and therefore the prototype is not copied with every new object instance. What does this mean in practice? It means that you can modify the prototype at any time and all objects (even those created before the modification) will inherit the changes."

Is there any way to prevent all objects from getting updated. I would like to keep the property's of each instance unique. If not are there any other methods from assigning property's to functions? Here's some code i'm working with. It allows me to display animated sprites in three.js but when I create new instances of the function the instances jump to the frame the new instance calls from. So there all displaying the same frame. i figured if I can turn of the inheritance It should be ok.  Sorry if it's sloppy I removed a bunch of stuff that's not needed for the question.

```
   function slowToStopFunc(texture, tilesHoriz, tilesVert, numTiles, tileDispDuration) {
       this.tilesHorizontal = tilesHoriz;
       this.tilesVertical = tilesVert;
       this.numberOfTiles = numTiles;
       texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
       texture.repeat.set( 1 / this.tilesHorizontal, 1 / this.tilesVertical );
       this.tileDisplayDuration = tileDispDuration;
       this.currentDisplayTime = 0;
       this.currentTile = 3;            
           this.update3 = function( milliSec3 ) {
            this.currentDisplayTime += milliSec3;
            while (this.currentDisplayTime > this.tileDisplayDuration && adjustSpeed <= 2)
            {
        if (this.currentTile >= -1 && this.currentTile <= 14) { 
           this.currentTile++;
           }
        }   
        var currentColumn = this.currentTile % this.tilesHorizontal;
        texture.offset.x = currentColumn / this.tilesHorizontal;
        var currentRow = Math.floor( this.currentTile /      this.tilesHorizontal );  
        texture.offset.y = currentRow / this.tilesVertical;
        }    
        }
```

Comment: can deep copy an object and thereby it will be standalone....is that what you want? A sample of that you are trying to acheive would be helpful

Comment: @charlietfl Yea sorry I should have put that up there to begin with. What your saying sounds about right.

Comment: so you are saying when you try `new slowToStopFunc` it reacts with other instances? Is that because `slowToStopFunc` is part of a bigger object?

Comment: I'm not really sure why it's reacting. After reading about prototype inheritance I figured the new instances were updating the old ones. That's what it looks like. slowToStopFunc is not part of another object. But I am calling new slowToStopFunc from with in another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nature of prototypal inheritance allows you to do this since the way property lookups are working.

When a property lookup occurs:

1. Does the object has *someProperty*? If yes return *someProperty*.
2. If the object doesn't have *someProperty*, check it's prototype chain and perform the same logic until it's prototype link is `null`.

Basically that means setting a property on an object will shadow it's inherited value naturally.

```
function A() {
}

A.prototype.test = 'test';

var a = new A();

a.test = 'test 2';

console.log(a.test); //not test anymore
```

However if you are asking if it's possible to modify a constructor's prototype without affecting the existing instances, it is possible but I do not know why you would like to do this.

Basically you just have to replace the whole prototype instance, so that newly created instances have a whole new prototype object.

```
function A() {}

A.prototype.test = 'test';

var a = new A();

A.prototype = {
    constructor: A,
    test: 'new value'
};

console.log(a.test); //test

console.log(new A().test); //new value
```

Comment: Thanks for the example code. I's there a way to replace the whole prototype instance when defining the property using this. and calling the function latter on using some thing like var Playanimation = new slowToStopFunc(texture, tilesHoriz, tilesVert, numTiles, tileDispDuration) {

Comment: @JohnBob Could you expand a bit more on "jump to the frame the new instance calls from", and also show how you are instanciating your stuff and what properties should be unique per instance. Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to use the code above to play an animation in three.js. It's works fine unless I add more then one animation. It seems like each instance of the animations are updating each other. In my code I have the line this.update3 = function( milliSec3 ) {. Then letter I call slowToStopFunc.update(1000*delta); I think every time each instance is updated it updates all of them.

Comment: Sure. I have a 16 image sprite sheet of a wheel spinning. In the code above this.currentTile is incremented. This is what tells the animation what image from the sprite sheet to display. So when one instance is on the screen the images display in the correct order but when I add more than one image things start to go wrong. Lets say wheel 1 is on image 5 and a new instance of wheel is called for.     now wheel 2 tries to call for image 1 and both wheel 1 and wheel display image 1 but then wheel 1 tries to call for image 6 and both wheels display image 6 and the 2 wheels fight over control.

Comment: @JohnBob By looking at your code, I have the feeling that all instances would share the same `texture` object. I have never used this library, but perhaps that's your issue. Also make sure that you are creating instances with the `new` keyword... `var instance = new slowToStopFunc(...);` Then updating... `instance.update(...);`. The name of the `slowTopStopFunc` function is quite misleading as well if it's a constructor.

Comment: Yea I create and update the instance like you say and your absolutely right about all instances sharing the same texture object

Comment: @JohnBob Perhaps you could setup a jsfiddle example. It would be easier to debug for me or anyone else.

Comment: I think you might have all ready found my issue. Having all the instances access the same texture object could be causing the same issue. I just want to ask one more question. The line of code "this.update3 = function( milliSec3 ) {" Normally when using "this." to define a method, should that method update multiple instances when invoked.

Comment: @JohnBob No, not at all, unless all instances would share a variable which is mutable (like an object). For example, if you set `MyClass.prototype.obj = {};` then all `MyClass` instances would share the same `obj`, so doing something like `this.obj.x = 1;` would impact all instances. That's normally why you do not put objects on the `prototype`, instead you initialize a new one inside the constructor e.g. `this.obj = {};`. Also please note that functions should be on the `prototype` because they can be shared across all instances.

Comment: Awesome thanks for clearing that up it's been giving me trouble for a bit now. Also I just changed my code so every time the animation is called it creates a new texture object and that fixed the issue. Of course this is causing me another issue. LOL. Now the first frame displays as just a black box. I think because the .png has not finished loading into memory yet. I't seems weird to me that a new image needs to be loaded into memory for each instance. I would think there was a way for the code to just reference one image to same memory. Well again thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try overriding inherited properties? Not sure how much you are familiar with object inheritance, but in general you can write over inherited properties by matching the name of properties.

Comment: Hmm interesting. How would I go about overriding properties?